# How can I manually show the splash screen in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

As per in older version of Phonegap, the splash screen is automatically handled. But on the recent releases, I don't see and splash screen for Android.

Do we need to write some more code to show the splash screen for all the platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show/hide splash screen using the splashscreen api.

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

Check more over here [Splashscreen API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen)